# What kind of grammatical structure is "all the time"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> You are meeting friends at the cinema ***all the time***.

Is "all the time" a preposition structure or a noun structure?

"all the time" means always do something.

I think "all the time" is a preposition structure which omits the preposition "for". If "all the time" is a noun structure, how can it modify other parts of the sentence? Can a noun structure function as an adverb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it an **adverbial** structure. In your example, it describes *when* you are meeting friends at the cinema.

Consider:

> You are making new friends daily.

There, *daily* is an adverb. In your sentence, the phrase *all the time* is functioning the same way.

Comment: @J.R.What are the traits of an adverbial structure? It seems that "all the time" is a noun structure.The noun structure is : determiner+ adjective+noun. "all"is a predeterminer, "the" is mid-determiner, and "time" is a noun.

Comment: @user48070 - _all the time_ is an idiom; it means "frequently" or "very often" or "regularly". Consequently, the word _time_ doesn't really function as a noun in the expression _all the time_.